# How to silence the logging of a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-import

#### Overview

I want to use `httpimport` as a logging library common to several scripts. This module generates logs of its own which I do not know how to silence.

In other cases such as this one, I would have used

```
logging.getLogger('httpimport').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

but it did not work.

#### Details

The following code is a stub of the "common logging code" mentioned above:

```
# toconsole.py

import logging
import os

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
handler_console = logging.StreamHandler()
level = logging.DEBUG if 'DEV' in os.environ else logging.INFO
handler_console.setLevel(level)
handler_console.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(handler_console)

# disable httpimport logging except for errors+
logging.getLogger('httpimport').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

A simple usage such as

```
import httpimport

httpimport.INSECURE = True
with httpimport.remote_repo(['githublogging'], 'http://localhost:8000/') :
    from toconsole import log

log.info('yay!')
```

gives the following output

```
[!] Using non HTTPS URLs ('http://localhost:8000//') can be a security hazard!
2019-08-25 13:56:48,671 yay!
yay!
```

The second (bare) `yay!` must be coming from `httpimport`, namely from its logging setup.

**How can I disable the logging for such a module, or better - raise its level so that only errors+ are logged?**

---

*Note: this question was [initially asked](https://github.com/operatorequals/httpimport/issues/15) at the Issues section of the GitHub repository for `httpimport` but the author did not know either how to fix that.*

Comment: There's guidance at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because when you do `import httpimport` they do the initial configuration for the logging machinery. This happens [right here](https://github.com/operatorequals/httpimport/blob/6b8145e565643bfa80dc08d8cb915bf4aefc0343/httpimport.py#L38). What this means is that the root logger already has a `StreamHandler` attached to it. Because of this, and the fact that all loggers inherit from the root logger, when you do `log.info('yay')` it not only uses your `Handler` and `Formatter`, but it also propagates all they way to the root logger, which also emits the message.

Remember that whoever calls `basicConfig` first when an application starts that sets up the default configuration for the root logger, which in turn, is inherited by all loggers, unless otherwise specified.

If you have a complex logging configuration you need to ensure that you call it before you do any third-party imports which might call `basicConfig`. `basicConfig` is **idempotent** meaning the first call seals the deal, and subsequent calls have no effect.

### Solutions

1. You could do `log.propagate = False` and you will see that the 2nd yay will not show.
2. You could attach the `Formatter` directly to the already existent root `Handler` by doing something like this (without adding another `Handler` yourself)

```
root = logging.getLogger('')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
root_handler = root.handlers[0]
root_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

3. You could do a `basicConfig` call when you initialize your application (if you had such a config available, with initial `Formatters` and `Handlers`, etc. that will elegantly attach everything to the root logger neatly) and then you would only do something like `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and `logger.info('some message')` that would work the way you'd expect because it would propagate all the way to the root logger which already has your configuration.
4. You could remove the initial `Handler` that's present on the root logger by doing something like

```
root = logging.getLogger('')
root.handlers = []
```

... and many more solutions, but you get the idea.

Also do note that `logging.getLogger('httpimport').setLevel(logging.ERROR)` this works perfectly fine. No messages below `logging.ERROR` would be logged by that logger, it's just that the problem wasn't from there.

If you however want to completely disable a logger you can just do `logger.disabled = True` (also do note, again, that the problem wasn't from the `httpimport` logger, as aforementioned)

### One example demonstrated

Change your *toconsole.py* with this and you won't see the second yay.

```
import logging
import os

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

root_logger = logging.getLogger('')
root_handler = root_logger.handlers[0]
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
root_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# or you could just keep your old code and just add log.propagate = False
# or any of the above solutions and it would work

logging.getLogger('httpimport').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 6):

Author of `httpimport` here.
I totally forgot I was using the `basicConfig` `logger` thing.

It is fixed in `master` right now (0.7.2) - will be included in next PyPI release:
https://github.com/operatorequals/httpimport/commit/ff2896c8f666c3f16b0f27716c732d68be018ef7